# How do I credit someone who made the trajectory file used for my thesis?

Tags: citations, citation-style

There's a trajectory file which I included a sample of in my Appendix. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Aside from stating in the Appendix text the name of the creator of the file, is there anything more I could do (like what they do for borrowed code: they insert the name of the creator in the code itself) ?

Comment: You can embed images into questions, as per my edit.

Comment: I don't understand your question: I understand you'll _stat[e] the name of the [file's] creator_, but what does _insert the name of the creator in the code itself_ mean? How can you insert the name of the creator into what looks like a table?

Comment: @user2768 Technical writing stuff like ending the caption of a Figure with "(Adapted from reference (60), Fig. 4)" is the proper way to credit the owner of a Figure, I'm just wondering how to do that for a sample of a file

Comment: Do it the same way, e.g., _Table ... (Source: XYZ.)_ or _Table ... [1]_.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the original author to put the data in a data repository (like Zeonodo or Figshare) and claim a doi for it. That makes the data object citeable in its own respect and you can give credit in a persistent way (as a bonus you get the author to think about licensing of their data).